# backup svn to another svn repository

Tags: svn, backup

I currently use one svn repository on one server, but to make it more failsafe. I have another svn repository set up on another server, how can I mirror the svn on my secondary server with the information in my svn on my primary server?

Comment: Do you use FSFS storage (the default) or BDB? If it's BDB you need to be careful just moving the files.

Comment: What do you want to achive? A backup of the files or a mirror of your svn repos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) from SVN itself which is able to replicate to an other server, but be aware of that the replicated repository is read only. The best thing is to replicate every commit via post-commit-hook script onto the backup server.

Comment: Not a great issue: I'd say that backups are normally read-only. IMHO, svnsync is the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

did you considered storing the second copy in a dump? in my opinion is the best way of making a save backup of your svn repository.

under windowsyou can use the following command:

```
svnadmin dump YourRepositoryPath > YourBackupName.svn
```

under linux you can use the following command:

```
svnadmin dump YourRepositoryPath | gzip > YourBackupName.svn.gz
```

maybe does not directly answer your question but maybe an idea for a different solution of the problem.

Best,
Ste

Comment: Another dummyes solution would be having 2 repository. and you can create your commit.sh script that will automatically commit in the 2 different repository. but i belive you tought aout this...

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to commercial solutions [Subversion Clustering](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/clustering) would keep it in sync and allow read-write at all nodes in the cluster.  This also works over a WAN.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [svk](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage), although it not actively developed any more.

Comment: SVK is not intended for backup purposes. It's like Git or Bazaar. It's intended to work off-line.

Comment: Given that the OP wants to mirror their primary repository, I'd say SVK fits the bill better than any of the answers they got so far. As far as I can tell all of the other suggestions require a task to be performed periodically.